# How to properly write SQL queries in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a database with two tables: `users` and `posts` where one user can have many posts.

I want to use plain SQL instead of ActiveRecord in some situations since plain SQL is faster.

There is a method `index` in my UsersController that looks like this:

```
def index
    @users = User.get_users_and_posts
end
```

This method returns users who have posts and returns their posts.
The `get_users_and_posts` method is implemented in my model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
 private

 def self.get_users_and_posts
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
     SELECT
       users.name, users.email, posts.title, posts.body
     FROM
       users
     INNER JOIN
       posts
     ON
       users.id = posts.user_id")
 end
```

Is this the proper way to write SQL queries in Rails? Does it follow the Rails Way?

Comment: _since plain SQL is faster_, faster than what?

Comment: "...faster than what?" exactly. SQL generated by Rails, by Sequel, or by hand are all running at full speed in the DBM. And, years ago, the SQL generated by ORMs was often pretty inefficient, but these days it's very good. Add to that the fact that the DBM optimizes the query prior to execution, and there begins to be big advantages to using the ORM for a developer who isn't an experienced DBA.

Comment: You're sacrificing code portability and convenience if you eschew Active Record for hand coding. Active Record makes it extremely easy to write syntactically correct SQL for many different DBMs, allowing you to use the same code in development and production often with only a change to the connection string. Try that with hand-coded SQL. Also, if, at some time in the future, another Rails developer takes over the support of the code, they don't need to know SQL, they just need to know Active Record, no matter what DBM platform the DB runs under. So "Does it follow the Rails Way?" No.

Comment: Comments above are unnecessarily dogmatic. Plenty of us have worked on DB-intensive applications where, yes, in fact, we can (and need to) sometimes *model certain things* a non-"standard" (by AR standards) way in the database and thus *query them* using raw SQL to get performance gains anywhere from 10-100x. It's not about my SQL being better than what AR generates, it's about needing to represent something in a way that AR cannot do (or cannot do as cleanly). OP asked for the right way to do raw SQL, commenters should respect that.

Comment: I should add that my assumption (unlike the other commenters) was that this *is not* an XY problem and that the OP simplified their example and knows why handwriting SQL would be more performant in their use case.

Answer (score 3):

You have basically nailed it! Make it more recyclable by using a variable for the SQL query, like so:

```
def self.get_users_and_posts
  sql = ("
     SELECT
       users.name, users.email, posts.title, posts.body
     FROM
       users
     INNER JOIN
       posts
     ON
       users.id = posts.user_id")
  result_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

`result_array` is the returned result of your SQL query in an array, which you can then iterate over.

Is it the proper way to write raw SQL queries in Ruby? Yes. As pointed out in [The Rails Way](http://index-of.es/Ruby/The%20Rails%20Way%20(2007).pdf):

> It is possible to use ActiveRecord’s underlying database connections
>   directly, and sometimes it is useful to do so from custom scripts and
>   for one-off or ad-hoc testing.

Although, Active Record is more ' The Rails way'...

> ActiveRecord expresses the *convention over configuration* philosophy
>   that is such an important part of the Rails way

...
I have worked on one particular DB heavy project where direct db connections, such as above, were essential for speed.

Comment: You don't need to store the result of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` since the last evaluated statement in a method body in Ruby is returned (by default).

Comment: Not sure why it has been down voted. I am interested. Comments welcome.

Comment: @SebastianPalma You are 100% correct, it is not necessary (but I didn't say it was). It is clearer though and shows what happens who may not have this fact clear.

Comment: @SharkLasers My guess is you had some downvotes because a lot of devs seem to believe using raw SQL is 100% always bad. Meanwhile, it's just another tool in the belt and, like you said, there are valid use cases in DB heavy projects where the performance gains of raw SQL is basically mandatory. (And can speed operations up by whole orders of magnitude.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write raw SQL in this case, you may need to write raw SQL but in this case you have a better solution which is provided in ActiveRecord.

Avoid N+1 queries in Rails, create your models with proper relations.

In the User Model:

```
has_many :posts
```

In the Post model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

In your controller or repository use `includes` to get users with posts:

```
User.includes(:posts)
```

The previous lines make only two queries:

1. Get Users.
2. Get Posts for all Users fetched.

Then it maps posts to their User in runtime.

In your previous example you make N+1 queries, one query to get users, and N queries to get posts for each user.

See "[10 Tips for Eager Loading to Avoid n+1 Queries in Rails](https://medium.com/@codenode/10-tips-for-eager-loading-to-avoid-n-1-queries-in-rails-2bad54456a3f)" for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will update the answer

Comment: how this ?
it must includes using a scope ?

Comment: Perhaps you must re-read the docs @thiaguerd or try it by yourself. `User.includes(:posts)` might return the same that `User.all` but they're in no way the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm sorry for that fault.
Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @magdy nice man keep it up